# Buttons in Zurb Orbit not hiding in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am putting together a site and grabbed Zurb's Orbit rotator out of their Foundation Framework for the home page. The site renders fine in all current browsers but the client has a requirement for IE8. The only issue I have left with IE8 is the buttons on the rotator are not taking on the Opacity settings of Orbit and therefore the buttons for all of the slides are showing when you visit the home page. Funny enough as the slide rotates through it takes the buttons with it and the rotator starts functioning as expected.

[Here is the site in question.](http://bapco.bluefishdesignstudio.com)

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should I be seeing any buttons? I'm getting an "image not found" for url("../images/foundation/orbit/right-arrow.png") (line 916 - bapco.css). Also, IE8's support for opacity is patchy: http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity

Comment: I too do not see any buttons.

Comment: There is a more info and buy button on each slide in the rotator.

Comment: Does anyone know if it is possible to make Orbit use display as the item that makes a slide active vs opacity?

Comment: Have you tried putting those buttons in something other than a div? What if you put them in a p element or something. Obv, the other elements don't all show at once, just the buttons, so either the <a> element is at fault or it's direct parent container is?

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Ultimately we decided that the functionality that we were getting from Orbit was not worth spending 2 days on so we moved to another script.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:

```css
.orbit-slide {display:none}
```

This should hide the slides until they are initialized

And remove this:

```css
.orbit .orbit-slide {right:0;}
```

That should prevent them from stacking on top of each other

Comment: I added the .orbit-slide bit and that did not seem to make any change at all.

Comment: from their docs page: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/orbit.php 

Note: We put some simple styles on our content slider, notably a background and padding on the div elements. Orbit stacks your slides, so transparent slides will will be visible on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Child elements in Orbit in IE8 will not adopt the settings. So Orbit sets the div element that contains the text to Opacity:0; but the child elements do not respect that setting. Ultimately we switched to another library that uses a mixture of Opacity and Display to control which slide is displayed.

Thanks for your help though. Much appreciated!